# How can I get video details for multiple videos in a single Vimeo API call?

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

YouTube has an option to retrieve video details (title, description, thumbnails...) using comma separated list of video IDs in a single call:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Is there such feature for Vimeo available? I don't see this option here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#_essentials

Creating album, channel etc is not an option if videos come from different sources..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's buried a bit, but the ability to make a batch request to get the metadata for multiple videos is documented here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#search_videos

In short, make a request to `/videos` with a query parameter `?uris=` and a comma-separated list of URI values.

For example, let's say you want to get metadata for videos at `/videos/111`, `/videos/222`, and `/videos/333`. The request would be formatted like this:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos?uris=/videos/111,/videos/222,/videos/333
```

Since this response can return a lot of metadata, I would consider using the [fields parameter](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter) so that only the metadata you need is returned. For the example above, that request would look like this if you wanted to get only the name, link, and video description back:

```
GET https://api.vimeo.com/videos?uris=/videos/111,/videos/222,/videos/333&fields=uri,link,name,description
```

Comment: Works fine, but too bad it doesnt skip invalid video urls from the list, instead it just returns one big error with no other data even if all other videos are correct. Youtube returns data for all correct videos and skips out invalid.

Answer (score -2):

Get video details for multiple videos in a single Vimeo API call

const URLVimeo = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos?uris=/videos/488610890,/videos/480833337,/videos/513912704';

```
   axios.get(URLVimeo, {    
          headers: {
                   'Authorization': 'bearer token',
                   'content-type': 'application/json' 
                  }
          }).then(res => {
```

});

Comment: This question is about the Vimeo API. You've answered with a YouTube API link. Are you saying that you can get Vimeo details from the YouTube API?