# Vimeo API to fetch detail of multiple video in single request by PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, curl, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have implemented functionality to fetch single video by video URL from Vimeo, below is code for that:

```
$json_url = 'https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' . $Videourl;
$ch = curl_init($json_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

From curl response, it returns with details like video duration, title etc.

Due to single curl request/response, it is taking more time, specially when I need to render multiple video details on web site page.

Is there any way, where I can send single request in PHP or javascript (where send multiple ID, URL of video) and receive information of multiple videos from Vimeo, so can increase loading time of the page and render content quickly?

Comment: Please see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54450918/6133426). I've tested it on [reqbin.com](https://reqbin.com/curl) with the following: `curl https://api.vimeo.com/videos?uris=/videos/891890036,/videos/891775405 -H "Authorization: bearer <BEARER_TOKEN>"` and it worked as expected. You would have to provide your access key / token, though.

Comment: @FiddlingAway I am facing an issue to get authorization token from vimeo portal, All my videos lies under library section, can you help me how I can get token from vimeo?

Comment: Sure: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/12427789081745-How-do-I-generate-a-personal-access-token

Comment: @FiddlingAway I haven't created any APP in Vimeo yet, Do I need to create app to get authorization token?

Comment: Yes, that's the first step (assuming you have a Vimeo account - if you don't, then creating and verifying the account is the first step).